# How to find which PPA contains a specific package?

Tags: ppa, repository

I would like to know which repository contains a specific package, in order to add the PPA link to the `sources.list` file.

The package can also be outside of the official repositories (`multiverse` or similar).

I dont want to find only the repository name but also the full qualified PPA link name to be added to the sources without any additional struggle.

Comment: Packet or package? Is there something after `:`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`y-ppa-manager` can do that for you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

Search the package and use the button <kbd>Add selected PPA</kbd> to add the PPA.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: the y-ppa-manager can not find libraw5 or libraw

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Sure, there is no package with that name for your Ubuntu version.

Comment: the program only searches for packages which are available for the system it is installed ? So, same programm on different ubuntu versions can display different results ?    Maybe you know if I need to have libraw5 in order to install lightzone or if i do not need any further package or already have another version that fulfills the purpose otherwise libraw5 would have done for another system . ..

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred Edit your originally question and add your Ubuntu version and that you need to install lightzone.

Comment: is there a command line utility that do the same ? I hate UI .. i just want to be able to search for something and if found in PPA to add the PPA automatically and then install the thing I was searching for with apt-get

Comment: this is always a pain point for me when using Ubuntu (I'm more on Arch these days). Glad to see a solution, but is there a command-line version, too? I really miss `yaourt` a lot which does exactly that in Arch/Manjaro.

Answer (score 9):

The fastest way to find the repository in which a package was published, is to search the [ubuntu package database](http://packages.ubuntu.com). For the package **aac-enc** we will find the following among entries for different releases:

```
http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=aac-enc
```

- [trusty (14.04LTS)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/aac-enc) (sound): Fraunhofer FDK AAC Codec Library - frontend binary [**multiverse**]
  0.1.2-1: amd64 i386

The repository will be printed bold in square brackets ([**multiverse**]).

---

A [personal package archive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) (PPA) is something different, as it allows everybody to upload any package there. Therefore there is an inherent risk to install packages with issues.

Searching for a PPA can be done from [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu):

```
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+search?text=aac-enc
```

will tell us that the package **aac-enc** is part of the package **fdk-aac**. On clicking on that we will be directed to a download page for different releases. Further down there is a link to versions in untrusted archives:

[image]

This links to an unsorted list of personal package archives containing *fdk-aac* but we can not limit this search to a defined release.

Comment: Nice, how to get from here the FULL qualified ppa link?

Comment: @mattobob Multiverse is already part of Ubuntu, you just need to enable it in your software sources.

Comment: Hey bro the question was specific for reporitories which are OUTSIDE multiverse.

Comment: There is no link to a PPA from packages.ubuntu - see edit.

Comment: I searched on launchpad.net for libraw5 and libraw, the package was found, but i can not find on those sites the launch-pad-username and ppa-name which are both necessary to know in order to add the PPA in the shell by typing add-apt-repository ppa:launchpadusername/ppa-name. HOw to obtain them there ?

Comment: @AbdulAlHazred: In the [PPA description](https://launchpad.net/~philip5/+archive/ubuntu/extra) there are instructions on how to add it to your system, including the name you should enter (**ppa:philip5/extra**).