# How to search for a ppa for the non community version of cinelerra?

Tags: ppa, launchpad, cinelerra

At this moment, the most recent version of cinelerra is 6.0.
I performed `apt-cache search cinelerra` on my ubuntu with 0 results, 
so I have to add a ppa which contains cinelerra.

There are two types of cinelerra, a less powerfull (so they say) called community version and a more powerfull heroine virtual (though I am noot 100 percent sure about this name) version.

I want to install the cinelerra - heroine virtual version.

My first step to add a ppa is usually to go to launchpad.net and perform a keywords search, in this case **cinelerra ppa**.

However, I am confused by the many search results and different namings, I am not quiet sure if I can spot the right version there.

Please help me by explaining what to pay attention to in the search results of launchpad.net or whether there are other sites to look for it.

Comment: Or https://askubuntu.com/questions/639493/how-to-find-which-ppa-contains-a-specific-package/639511#639511

Answer (score 1):

I would 1st start by going to the website of that software. In this case they have added a pretty nice download page with instructions. Here you pick the one you want (there are 3 versions, 2 have Ubuntu listed): https://cinelerra-cv.org/download.php and choosing Ubuntu for the community edition it shows you install it with

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cinelerra-ppa/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install cinelerra-cv
```

This will install "Cinelerra-CV" See the 1st link what features it holds.

And that is it.

---

That page also has a "Cinelerra-GG" (Good Guy). This version is updated more often. And it also has version specific installs:

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common apt-transport-https
```

For Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty Tahr), run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://cinelerra-cv.org/five/pkgs/ub14
```

For Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus), run:

```
sudo apt-add-repository https://cinelerra-cv.org/five/pkgs/ub16
```

It also status you need to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change the repo it added to: `deb [trusted=yes] https://cinelerra-cv.org/five/pkgs/ub16 xenial main` due to a more strict licensing.

Nothing on 17.04 so use the 16.04 version.  After adding it do a ..

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cin
```